# Grunt compass and sass/css directory

Tags: css, node.js, sass, compass-sass, gruntjs

I updated the latest version of grunt (0.4.1) and installed the compass package (grunt-contrib-compass).
Here the config I use:

```
compass: {                  
  dist: {                   
    options: {              
      sassDir : "src/theme/sass",
      cssDir : "src/theme/css",
      imagesDir: "src/theme/img",
      javascriptsDir : "src/js",
      fontsDir : "src/theme/fonts",
      environment : "production"
    }
  }
}
```

Every time a change occurres in the sass directory, the compass task is executed and the css directory is created (with the production css files).
Everything is good but **the css files, the config.rb files and the sass cache are also recopied in the sass directory.**

Has someone ran into the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you have a `config.rb`, consider actually using it:

```
compass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      config: 'config/config.rb'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Still the same! It seems that it comes from the livereload plugin I nstalled with sublime text

Comment: Try removing the misplaced files and running the app without using any tools. Do the misplaced files appear again?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I ran into this problem once. But the problem was me running the `compass` command instead of `grunt compass` so default configuration was been used.